# Inherit from asp.net control: how to add a custom attribute with ViewState support

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, custom-server-controls

I have an ASP.NET custom server control which inherits from LinkButton. It adds a custom attribute, which appears correctly on the client side as data-attribute="value" inside the  anchor tag. So far so good.

Now I want to modify the value of that data-attribute on the client side, and have the server control see it change. However although I persist the server value in ViewState, I do not know how to tell ASP.NET to load the value back from the client.

[Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which perhaps does that for ControlState, but I really want to use ViewState, and I think it should be easy, if only I knew how...

What do I have to do to get that attribute value maintained in ViewState by ASP.NET across post backs please?

Comment: have you ever solved this problem? i need too :(